# android how to move image with seekbar?

Tags: android

I am using a gallery in which images are coming from a server. I have used a seekbar which moves with images. The problem is that when I move the seekbar, my image is not moving and not showing according to seekbar count. What do I do? I'm searching for this for 2 days. Please help me, thank you.

```
public class ReaderScreen extends Activity implements IServerResponse{

private Gallery gallery =null;
private SeekBar mybar =null;
ArrayList<String> _issueList= new ArrayList<String>();
private Gallery imagesComics = null;
private JSONArray post;
String _coverImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.reader_screen);

    mybar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    gallery=(Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    //  imagesComics =(Gallery) findViewById(R.id.images_comic);



    gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            //      mySelection.setText(" selected option: " + position );
            //  for(int i =0;i<post.length();i++){
            _coverImage=_issueList.get(position);
            mybar.setProgress(position);


            //  }

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            //  mySelection.setText("Nothing selected");

        }


    });


    mybar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int seekValue = mybar.getProgress();

            Toast.makeText(ReaderScreen.this,""+seekValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //  seekBar.setProgress(post.length());
            seekBar.setMax(post.length());


        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int seekValue = mybar.getProgress();
            //   _issueList.set(seekValue, _coverImage);
            Toast.makeText(ReaderScreen.this,""+seekValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //   Toast.makeText(ReaderScreen.this,"onStopTrackingTouch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    issues_images_WS(); 
}

private Handler _handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        String respons=msg.obj.toString();
        switch (msg.arg1) {
        case Constant.PID_ISSUES_IMAGES:
            if(respons!=null){
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(respons);
                    /*JSONArray*/ post=jsonObj.getJSONArray("List of image URLs");
                    for(int i =0;i<post.length();i++){
                        String values = post.getString(i);
                        _issueList.add(values);
                    }
                    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(ReaderScreen.this,_issueList));
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
};
// SERVER RESPONSE METHOD
public void serverResponse(String response, int processid) {
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.arg1 = processid;
    msg.obj = response;
    _handler.sendMessage(msg);
}

public void issues_images_WS() {
    if (NetworkAvailablity.checkNetworkStatus(ReaderScreen.this)) {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> requestParaList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", Constant.USER_ID));
        requestParaList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("issue_id", "1"));

        WebServiceCommunicator.getInstance().registerForServerResponse(
                (IServerResponse) ReaderScreen.this);
        WebServiceCommunicator.getInstance().callGetAppWebService(
                Constant.showDialog, this, WebServiceConstants.getMethodUrl(WebServiceConstants.METHOD_NAME_GET_ISSUES_IMAGES),
                ReaderScreen.this, Constant.PID_ISSUES_IMAGES, false,
                requestParaList);
    } else {
        Constant.showAlertDialog(Constant.errorTitle,
                Constant.MSG_CHECK_INTERNET_SETTING,
                ReaderScreen.this, false);

    }
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    /** The parent context */
    private Context myContext;
    ArrayList<String> _issueList1= new ArrayList<String>();
    private UserImageLoaderWithCache cache=null;

    // Put some images to project-folder: /res/drawable/
    // format: jpg, gif, png, bmp, ...
    /*private int[] myImageIds = { R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                   R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher };*/

    /** Simple Constructor saving the 'parent' context. */
    public ImageAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<String> list) {
        this.myContext = c;
        this._issueList1 = list;
        cache=new UserImageLoaderWithCache(c);
    }
    private class ViewHolder{

        public ImageView issuesimages;

    }
    // inherited abstract methods - must be implemented
    // Returns count of images, and individual IDs
    public int getCount() {
        return this._issueList1.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    // Returns a new ImageView to be displayed,
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, 
            ViewGroup parent) {



        View v = convertView;
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if(v==null){
            viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater linf = (LayoutInflater) myContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = linf.inflate(R.layout.imageview, null);
            viewHolder.issuesimages=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image_view_comic);
            v.setTag(viewHolder);
        }else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        String imageUrl=_issueList1.get(position);
        viewHolder.issuesimages.setTag(imageUrl);
        cache.display(imageUrl,viewHolder.issuesimages, R.drawable.loading);
        return v;

    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: have you done your all project with other people help?? plz gime defination of it i will make it and give you all code ;)

Comment: @DigveshPatel no sir..,its not my project..,my senior has given me littile part for project..,and i am solving that issues only...:).,and images are not moving with seekbar...:(

Comment: hmmm in which company u r?? i think your seniour dosent have any idea about how to manage project and so on

Comment: actuallu i didnot understand your question plz give some grapics so i get some idea

Comment: sir ii have used gallery in which images are coming from server,now with this i have used seekbar,for moving images from left to right..,the problem is that.,according to seekbar position and count value that particular image is not showing, and i want to show that...,sir its on my job..,please help me....:(

Comment: sry dear i have not getting any idea for that cause at this time so many work i have so i have done today ni8 and post you answer

Comment: when does your gallery item gets selected?? when image is loaded completely?? where is the code for that??

Answer (score 0):

if you simply want to change images then instead of gallery you should use image View

and

```
@Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int seekValue = mybar.getProgress();

            Toast.makeText(ReaderScreen.this, "" + seekValue,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // seekBar.setProgress(post.length());
            seekBar.setMax(5);
            gallery.setImageResource(_issueList.get(seekValue));

        }
```

gallery.setImageResource(_issueList.get(seekValue))
should be changing accordingly you should have images in _issueList

```
_issueList.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    _issueList.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    _issueList.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    _issueList.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    _issueList.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Comment: if this is not you exactly looking for then please elaborate your requirement,happy coding

Comment: actully i have used gallery for images and my images are coming from server.i have used one seekbar whcih is moving with image s.,but problem is that i want that if seekbar value is 10 then 10th image sholud be seen and move..,but its not happening , i am so confuse please help me...,

Comment: sir..,i want to set position of image at start scrooll and stop scrolll,what i do

Comment: sir..,its giving me error on gallery.setImageResource(_issueList.get(seekValue)); this line..

Comment: what is the error ?
is it compile time of it is run time exception?
i mean is it crashing or your are not able to run the app ?

Comment: sir the error is..,The method setImageResource(int) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (String)...

Comment: its comiple time error..,when i am writing this code in [ gallery.setImageResource(_issueList.get(seekValue));] in onprogresschanged

Comment: have you initialized variables

Comment: gallery.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(_issueList.get(seekValue)));

Comment: gallery.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(_issueList.get(seekValue))); i used this but its giving arrayout of bound execption

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip" />
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="5" />
```

this is your xml

```
public class ReaderScreen extends Activity {

private ImageView gallery = null;
private SeekBar mybar = null;
ArrayList<Integer> _issueList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private Gallery imagesComics = null;
private JSONArray post;
String _coverImage;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.reader_screen);
    _issueList.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    _issueList.add(R.drawable.device_one);
    _issueList.add(R.drawable.device_four);
    _issueList.add(R.drawable.device_therre);
    _issueList.add(R.drawable.device_two);
    mybar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    gallery = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    // imagesComics =(Gallery) findViewById(R.id.images_comic);

    /*gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            // mySelection.setText(" selected option: " + position );
            // for(int i =0;i<post.length();i++){
        //  _coverImage = _issueList.get(position);
            mybar.setProgress(position);

            // }

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // mySelection.setText("Nothing selected");

        }

    });*/

    mybar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int seekValue = mybar.getProgress();

            Toast.makeText(ReaderScreen.this, "" + seekValue,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // seekBar.setProgress(post.length());
            seekBar.setMax(5);
            gallery.setImageResource(_issueList.get(seekValue));

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int seekValue = mybar.getProgress();
            // _issueList.set(seekValue, _coverImage);
            Toast.makeText(ReaderScreen.this, "" + seekValue,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Toast.makeText(ReaderScreen.this,"onStopTrackingTouch",
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    //issues_images_WS();
}


// SERVER RESPONSE METHOD
public void serverResponse(String response, int processid) {
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.arg1 = processid;
    msg.obj = response;
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    /** The parent context */
    private Context myContext;
    ArrayList<Integer> _issueList1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // Put some images to project-folder: /res/drawable/
    // format: jpg, gif, png, bmp, ...
    /*
     * private int[] myImageIds = { R.drawable.ic_launcher,
     * R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,
     * R.drawable.ic_launcher };
     */

    /** Simple Constructor saving the 'parent' context. */
    public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        this.myContext = c;
        this._issueList1 = list;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {

        public ImageView issuesimages;

    }

    // inherited abstract methods - must be implemented
    // Returns count of images, and individual IDs
    public int getCount() {
        return this._issueList1.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // Returns a new ImageView to be displayed,
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (v == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater linf = (LayoutInflater) myContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = linf.inflate(R.layout.imageview, null);
            viewHolder.issuesimages = (ImageView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.image_view_comic);
            v.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.issuesimages.setImageResource(_issueList1.get(position));
 //         String imageUrl = _issueList1.get(position);
 //         viewHolder.issuesimages.setTag(imageUrl);
        return v;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: this will change images on progress of seek bar